How do I change the SDK version in Visual Studio 2022?
I started work on a new .NET C# project on my laptop, which had the .NET 9 SDK installed.  When it came time for me to clone the project's Git repo onto my desktop, I didn't realize that the desktop still had the .NET 8 SDK installed, and so Visual Studio 2022 gave me error NETSDK1045.  Specifically, the error says

The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 9.0.  Either target .NET 8.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 9.0.  Download the .NET SDK from https://aka.ms/dotnet/download.

Okay, so I had the wrong version installed.  Mistakes happen.  So I downloaded and installed the .NET 9 SDK and...the same error happened.  I'm probably missing something stupid, but I don't know what it is.
I tried clicking the Install other frameworks link in the project properties, but that just sent me to the same page to download the (already downloaded) .NET 9 SDK.
I also tried deleting the .NET 8 SDK, but then the project wouldn't load at all.

Hi, I remembered that VS shall use the latest .Net version by default, based on this document it looks like your client should work well. May I know whether it worked after you tried a restart? Have you tried to clean the solution after installed .Net 9 SDK?
